# SDXC Card or USB 3 pen drive - which one should I buy, and which one is better

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware-recommendation, sd-card

I have MacBook Air (13", Mid 2013) and my father has MacBook Pro (13", Mid 2012). Both MacBooks have SDXC card slot, and both support/ has USB 3 ports.

We are thinking of moving iPhoto library to portable drive (either SDXC card or USB 3 pen drive) to save space on internal HDD

What is recommended - SDXC Card or USB 3 drive, and for what reason like speed, consistency, etc?

Also, it would be of great help if you can provide which one to buy. For example, if you suggest SDXC card, then which cards (Sandisk, etc) should I look forward to buy. Thanks.

Comment: How big is the iPhoto library? Why not go somewhere in the direction of a NAS where you can both be attached to the share without actually plugging something directly into the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Read/Write speeds to enable you to make a decision as to what best suits your needs. This question is asking for people's opinions which is a bit tricky

Answer (score 1):

As for speed USB 3.0 runs circles around SDXC cards. See Ed Tittel's great article on comparison: http://www.edtittel.com/blog/a-tale-of-tablet-storage-usb-3-vs-micro-sdxc.html

Answer (score 0):

The point is you cannot know this, it's based on the manufacturer and build-quality.
Each manufacturer **will claim** they **only use the best products** and will convince you their product is the fastest etc.

I think either both of them will be fine, at least better than USB 2.0 or even 1.5 we've had in the past :)

Also I doubt you have to transfer multiple Tera- or Petabytes of Photo's do you?

Besides that, the speed does not only differ because of SDXC or 3.0. There's also processor, RAM and undoubtly more factors.

To get specifically back to your question, I've copied my Photos and Videos via USB 3.0 as I had the disk already. If you have one of both, just use it.